# Flashy background image

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, macos

I have an application and want to use the flash effect with glitters feature as the background to my UIView. Any reply on this would be a greater help for me.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: use alpha property of image with UIAnimation

Answer (score 1):

Do you have this as an image? Then you could try -

`[view setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"glitters_image.png"]]];`